# Table names as variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have been using prepared statements with PDO and I have found that table names cannot be bound. While I can use something like `$sql = "select * from $table_name where something = :something"`

If the $table_name variable is assigned internally by a method by running a query and getting the value from the database, is this method safe? Or is it bad practice to have variable table names? If it is opinion based, I'd like to know your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

There are situations when you must use dynamic table names, so this is an acceptable practice. Personally, I would double check if this requirement is a must and if not, then hard code the table names in the queries.

If the table name comes from a user input, then I would use white listing as a security measure: get list of table names from mysql's information_schema and compare them to the input **in the application code** to avoid any aql injection.

If the table name comes from mysql's **information_schema**, then that's it, you can use it without any further checks because it is a valid table name. Just put backticks around the name.

If the table name comes from a table created by the application, then I would again simply retrieve the list of tables via the information_schema and check if it existed in the application code. This ensures that the table name is valid.